# Problems with option selection in Chrome and Opera

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, dom

I've Problems with thise Code, it's working fine in Firefox and Internet Explorer but it doesn't work with Opera and Chrome Browsers...

```
<script>
function planetselect()
{
optionen=document.getElementById('pstart').options;
for(i=0;i<optionen.length;i++)
{
if(optionen[i].value==67080)
{
  optionen[i].setAttribute('selected','selected');
  }
}
optionen=document.getElementById('pdest').options;
for(i=0;i<optionen.length;i++)
{
if(optionen[i].value==67080)
{
  optionen[i].setAttribute('selected','selected');
  }
}
}</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
optionen[i].setAttribute('selected','selected');
```

to

```
optionen[i].selected = true;
```

More generally, avoid the use of `setAttribute` to change DOM properties. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

From [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.setAttribute) :

> Using setAttribute() to modify certain attributes, most notably value
>   in XUL, works inconsistently, as the attribute specifies the default
>   value. To access or modify the current values, you should use the
>   properties. For example, use elt.value instead of
>   elt.setAttribute('value', val).

Answer (score 1):

Did you make sure you close the `<script>` tag? I can't really see a problem with your code that you posted, so either you didn't close your tag, or your `optionen` or `options` variables aren't there or valid

Also too, you should know that chrome has a javascript console that should show you any errors you have. To open it, it's `ctrl-shift-j`. That should help you a lot.